# Using python and PIL how can I grab a block of text in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, python-2.7

I have an image (*.png) which contains two blocks of text. I am trying to grab each block of text individually using the python imaging library (PIL) in python27.

I have tried to blur the image and then find the edges of the blurred block so that I can then recover the boundaries of each block (for use later with "crop"). However when I blur the image (I've tried several iterations) the "find_edges" filter simply seems to grab the edges of each character.

```
pic = Image.open("a.jpg")
out = pic.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
out = out.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
```

I guess I'm looking for something similar the photoshop "Magnetic Lasso Tool" Any idea what approach may be better?

Comment: Yes, the Find Edges filter in PIL is like the one of the same name in Photoshop. It traces the edges detected in the image -- solid shapes get turned into outlines.

Comment: That is what I am after, however I'd like the whole text block to be outlined rather than each individual character, which is what is happening at the moment (despite the blurring).

Comment: and what about simply creating a function that would get a bounding box out of your edges? If you have the coordinates of the latter, you can have the extrema

Comment: As a start, you can look at this answer I posted earlier today about removing whitespace with `PIL` and `numpy` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396312/use-python-pil-or-similar-to-shrink-whitespace/9398422#9398422 Once you have the outer boundary you can do sometime similar to find the inner portions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would start by making a histogram of the image projected onto one axis. Take your image, [crop to the outer bounding box first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396312/use-python-pil-or-similar-to-shrink-whitespace/9398422#9398422). An example of the projected histogram onto to the y-axis:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("dummytext.png")
pix = np.asarray(im)
pix = pix[:,:,0:3] # Drop the alpha channel
pix = 255 - pix  # Invert the image
H =  pix.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1) # Sum the colors, then the y-axis
```

[image]

From here, identify the largest block of white space. This determines the best y-coordinate to split at. Note how it is obvious in the histogram above. If the two text blocks are closer together you'll need a better criteria, just adapt the method to fit your needs. Once split you can crop the images separately.

Comment: What a nice post -- It should have been accepted as the answer!

Comment: @srking Thanks, I'm glad it was useful to you. I'm not too worried about the acceptance, that's what the upvotes are for!