# Numpy PIL Python : crop image on whitespace or crop text with histogram Thresholds

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

How would I go about finding the bounding box or window for the region of whitespace surrounding the numbers in the image below?:

## Original image:

[image]

Height: 762 pixels
Width: 1014 pixels

## Goal:

Something like: `{x-bound:[x-upper,x-lower], y-bound:[y-upper,y-lower]}` so I can crop to the text and input into tesseract or some OCR.

## Attempts:

I had thought of slicing the image into hard coded chunk sizes and analysing at random, but i think it would be too slow.

Example code using `pyplot` adapted from ([Using python and PIL how can I grab a block of text in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402765/using-python-and-pil-how-can-i-grab-a-block-of-text-in-an-image)):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = Image.open('/home/jmunsch/Pictures/Aet62.png')
p = np.array(im)
p = p[:,:,0:3]
p = 255 - p
lx,ly,lz = p.shape

plt.plot(p.sum(axis=1))
plt.plot(p.sum(axis=0))

#I was thinking something like this 
#The image is a 3-dimensional ndarray  [[x],[y],[color?]]
#Set each value below an axes mean to 0
[item = 0 for item in p[axis=0] if item < p.mean(axis=0)]

# and then some type of enumerated groupby for each axes
#finding the mean index for each groupby(0) on axes

plt.plot(p[mean_index1:mean_index2,mean_index3:mean_index4])
```

Based on the graphs each of the valleys would indicate a place to bound.

- The first graph shows where lines of text would be
- The second graph shows where characters would be

## Plot example `plt.plot(p.sum(axis=1))`:

[image]

## Plot example output `plt.plot(p.sum(axis=0))`:

[image]

Related posts/docs:

- [Trim whitespace using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615901/trim-whitespace-using-pil)
- [Using python and PIL how can I grab a block of text in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402765/using-python-and-pil-how-can-i-grab-a-block-of-text-in-an-image)
- [Use Python / PIL or similar to shrink whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396312/use-python-pil-or-similar-to-shrink-whitespace/9398422#9398422)
- [Crop the image using PIL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983263/crop-the-image-using-pil-in-python)
- [Rectangular bounding box around blobs in a monochrome image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525313/rectangular-bounding-box-around-blobs-in-a-monochrome-image-using-python?rq=1)
- [How can I improve my paw detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087919/how-can-i-improve-my-paw-detection?lq=1)
- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html

## update: solution by HYRY

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "region"? You want the coordinates for a rectangle that contains the letters in your first image? What does it need to generalize to?

Comment: numpy just does arrays (and some basic stats, etc..). It sounds like you need a computer vision library like [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/). Especially if you don't want a bounding box for only this image (which you could probably eyeball).

Comment: I appreciate the tip on a Computer Vision library, but `numpy` can manipulate arrays, which can then be converted back to images with `PIL`. As an example:  `pix = np.array(im);cropped_to_corner = Image.fromarray(pix[0:200,0:200])` Just figured out how to get at the x-axis

Comment: What's your question, then? If you could rephrase it, or say what you've tried, it might be a little more clear what you're trying to accomplish. I don't know how the code you posted relates to your question.

Comment: @machow Apologies for the confusing question. I tried to reword it after doing some reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use Morphology functions in `scipy.ndimage`, here is an example:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
img = pl.imread("Aet62.png")[:, :, 0].astype(np.uint8)
img2 = ndimage.binary_erosion(img, iterations=40)
img3 = ndimage.binary_dilation(img2, iterations=40)
labels, n = ndimage.label(img3)
counts = np.bincount(labels.ravel())
counts[0] = 0
img4 = labels==np.argmax(counts)
img5 = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(img4)
result = ~img & img5
result = ndimage.binary_erosion(result, iterations=3)
result = ndimage.binary_dilation(result, iterations=3)
pl.imshow(result, cmap="gray")
```

the output is:

[image]

Comment: very cool. I'll probably use `-result` for tesseract. Is it overall just a bad idea trying to use histograms? (e.g. http://scipy-lectures.github.io/packages/scikit-image/#histogram-based-method-otsu-thresholding ) For the less mathematically inclined like myself?